# Animating child component from parent component

Tags: angular, animation

I am looking to animate a child component while the button that triggers the animation is in the parent component. For now, I added the trigger to the child component tag in the parent component but it does not work. Should I add the animation in the child component directly ?

```
 <app-subscription-details *ngIf="onShow" [doctors]="organisation.doctors" [idOrg]="organisation.id"
    [@openClose]="onShow ? 'default' : 'showed'"  ></app-subscription-details>
```

Animation in the ts of the parent:

```
trigger('openClose', [
  state('default', style({
    height: '0'
  })),
  state('showed', style({
    height: '100%'
  })),
  transition('default <=> showed', [
    animate('0.2s ease-in-out')
  ])
])
```

My goal is to show the child component when the user will click on a button.

I did try to put the whole animation with the trigger in the child component with an Input that would transfer the variable but it does not work as well.

Cheers

Comment: This is probably working fine, however, you need to add some css to app-subscription-details because just setting height is probably not doing much without a blocking element and and overflow:hidden..

Comment: You are right, when I inspect the element, I can see the css I put in my animations. So it is just that my css is broken xD

Comment: So I did some testing, and when I inspect the component, I can see the CSS I added via the animations, but it is not firing per se when I click on the trigger. The subcomponent just spawns out of nowhere (which is the default behavior)

Comment: I used things like transform:translateY(x). So when I put it manually in the inspector, I see the component moving but there is no animation when done through the navigator.